# How to get percentage of rows meeting a criterion in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi consider that I have this table

```
create table process(process_id serial, state text);
insert into process(process_id, state) values(1, 'DONE'),
                                          (2, 'DONE'),
                                          (3, 'DONE'),
                                          (4, 'FAILED');
```

now if you run:

```
select distinct(state),count(*) a from process group by state;
```

you will get two rows: FAILED 1, DONE 3
what I want is to get the percentage of failed processes which is = FAILED/(FAILED+DONE).

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct(state), count(*)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct state, count(*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method in Postgres uses `avg()`:

```
select avg( (state = 'FAILED')::int )
from process;
```

You can add `where state in ('FAILED', 'DONE')` if you have other statuses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case ... when` for that. To avoid integer division you need to also convert one of the numbers to float:

```
select cast(count(case state when 'FAILED' then 1 end) as float) / count(*) a 
from process;
```

Alternatively, you can also use `nullif`:

```
select cast(count(nullif(state, 'DONE')) as float) / count(*) a 
from process;
```

Comment: According to [PostgreSQL 9.4 aggregation filters: They do pay off](http://www.cybertec.at/postgresql-9-4-aggregation-filters-they-do-pay-off/), `count(*) FILTER (WHERE ...)` is slightly faster than `count(CASE ... THEN 1 END)`.

Comment: The approaches listed only work if `FAILED` and `DONE` are the only states.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FILTER` to narrow which rows are counted:

```
SELECT CAST(count(*) FILTER (WHERE state = 'FAILED') AS float)
       / count(*)
FROM process
WHERE state in ('FAILED', 'DONE');
```

See [Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) in the PostgreSQL docs for more details. The first count is cast to `float` to prevent integer truncation when dividing.

The filter on states being in either `FAILED` or `DONE` is done in the `WHERE` clause rather than an aggregate filter to ensure any indexes on the `state` column can be used.